# debug is not saving under debug.log

Tags: java, xml, servlets, logging, log4j

I have created an application using log4j using xml configuration, the applications saves logs based on levels,..ierror logs to error.log, info logs to info.log.

The application is working fine but debug logs is not saving under debug.log file. rest all logs are saving correctly

can anyone please tell me some solution for this

My **log4jConfig.xml** is as given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="debug-out" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${openfireHome}/logs/debug.log" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1024KB"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-7p %10c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMax" value="debug" />
            <param name="LevelMin" value="debug" />
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="info-out" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${openfireHome}/logs/info.log" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1024KB"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-7p %10c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMax" value="info" />
            <param name="LevelMin" value="info" />
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="warn-out" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${openfireHome}/logs/warn.log" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1024KB"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-7p %10c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMax" value="warn" />
            <param name="LevelMin" value="warn" />
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="error-out" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${openfireHome}/logs/error.log" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1024KB"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-7p %10c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="error" />
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="debug-out" />
        <appender-ref ref="info-out" />
        <appender-ref ref="warn-out" />
        <appender-ref ref="error-out" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

**StartupListener.java**

```
package com.log4jdemo;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;

public class StartupListener implements ServletContextListener
{
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)
    {
        ServletContext servletContext = event.getServletContext();
        System.setProperty("openfireHome", servletContext.getRealPath("/"));

        Logger logger = null;
        String log4jFile = servletContext.getInitParameter("log4jConfig");
        System.out.println(log4jFile);
        DOMConfigurator.configure(log4jFile);
        logger = LogManager.getLogger(StartupListener.class.getName());
        logger.debug("Loaded: " + log4jFile);

        logger.info("This is a logging statement from log4j");
        logger.debug("Show DEBUG message");
        logger.info("Show INFO message");
        logger.warn("Show WARN message");
        logger.error("Show ERROR message");
        logger.fatal("Show FATAL message");
        System.out.println(servletContext.getRealPath("/")+"/WEB-INF/logs/");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the root logger level. If you require *all* levels, you can put the following::

```xml
<root>
   <level value="all" />
   <appender-ref ref="debug-out" />
   <appender-ref ref="info-out" />
   <appender-ref ref="warn-out" />
   <appender-ref ref="error-out" />
</root>
```

The following are the levels available in log4j:

```
Level
----- 
ALL   # Everything is written.
TRACE
DEBUG
INFO 
WARN 
ERROR
FATAL
OFF   # Nothing is written.
```

`ALL` and `OFF` are special levels.

If you requiere one log with all levels, add an appender unfiltered and without threshold. e.g.:

```
<appender name="out" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${openfireHome}/logs/out.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1024KB"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-7p %10c{1} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

And in the root logger:

```
<root>
    <level value="all" />
    <appender-ref ref="out" />
    <appender-ref ref="debug-out" />
    <appender-ref ref="info-out" />
    <appender-ref ref="warn-out" />
    <appender-ref ref="error-out" />
</root>
```

Comment: If I want one log file also to hold all the level based logs...what I have to do

Comment: Indeed. You've only specified `LevelMin` in your `error-out` appender.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of your root level:

```
<root>
        <level value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="debug-out" />
        <appender-ref ref="info-out" />
        <appender-ref ref="warn-out" />
        <appender-ref ref="error-out" />
</root>
```

you need to set the level value to "debug"

DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR

DEBUG being the most detailed among the four

Since your have kept it at INFO, all the log levels below that are printing correctly.

Comment: So I need to change to `<level value="debug" />` instead of `<level value="info"/>`.... also if I do this will I get all other logs...or do I miss any other

Comment: yup. you won't miss any from what you have in your code. TRACE is the most detailed one. Read this for more: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html